# Remove ExtendedClass properties when casting from ExtendedClass to BaseClass

Tags: c#

I am not sure whether I am doing this right or whether it is just not possible through casting. I have 2 classes. The base class: `SQLiteDb.ScrapeSession` and the another class extended from that class called; `ScrapeSessions.ScrapeSession`. I am trying to down cast the ScrapeSessions.ScrapeSession object to the SQLiteDb.ScrapeSession and keep just the properties that exist in SQLiteDb.ScrapeSession. But my casting does not work. This is my method;

```
private async void StartTimerScrapeAsync(ScrapeSessions.ScrapeSession Session)
{
    int s = await SQLiteDb.db.InsertAsync((SQLiteDb.ScrapeSession)Session);
    ScrapeSessions.ScrapeSession ScrapeSession = (ScrapeSessions.ScrapeSession)await SQLiteDb.db.FindAsync<SQLiteDb.ScrapeSession>(s);
    ScrapeSession.Timer = Session.Timer;
    Scraper TimerScraper = new Scraper();
    TimerScraper.LiveExcelProcess = true;
    TimerScraper.SaveToArchieve = true;
    TimerScraper.Start(ScrapeSession);
}
```

`SQLiteDb.ScrapeSession` has several other properties including Timer which cause `await SQLiteDb.db.InsertAsync((SQLiteDb.ScrapeSession)Session);` to fail because the method sees these properties

Comment: If casting can't do that then what is the point of casting?

Comment: `But my casting does not work.` What about it **specifically** doesn't work?

Comment: Casting from child class to parent does not actually change the object. It will still have the same type as before, so if `InsertAsync` inspects your type with reflection - casting won't help.

Comment: @user5500750 How exactly does it "fail"? Please edit your question to include the complete error message you get when calling `InsertAsync()`. Also, add the complete remaining source code and maybe the table/column definition you have in your SQLite DB.

Comment: It looks like Casting will not work here since it does not remove properties in the result. I remember when I first started C#. I can across several script samples that can take an object properties and copy it into object. I think it involved something to do with `Reflection`. And I think it work like an extension. An example like that would be nice.